# Dual Boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu Ideapad Y400

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, uefi, lenovo

Before this, I always dual boot ubuntu alongside with windows. Im also helping my friend to do it. But my old laptop Dell Latitude D635 had been replaced with Lenovo Ideapad Y400. Below is the spec :

Y400, i7-3630QM + Nvidia GT750M, 4GB, 500GB, W8, 120wPSU, swappable ODD

The windows preinstalled is in UEFI mode. So, I try to install it the normal way I installed ubuntu. When boot from usb, I have two options. EFI Kingston or Kingston. So i choose EFI Kingston as I know that time my windows in UEFI mode. But after done installing, I reboot and it went to windows... It didnt show usual grub menu, but automatically go to windows, Like i didnt install ubuntu. By default secure boot is disable. So what should I do so I can dual boot it with my Win8? Hope pro here can help me. Or is there any Y400 user here? I preferred 12.04 though as it support till 2017. No need to upgrae everytime.

Comment: Is there any tutorial about this? Searched for 2months now...BUMP

Answer (score 1):

Try running the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool. If that doesn't help, post the URL to the summary data that the tool provides to you.

Comment: Thx bro, is there any setting should I use in the boot repair? or just leave default? Btw where should i install the bootloader? need to create extra 400mb boot partition?